# Mutual Exclusion case

Tags: mutex

Hi I have following question:

I have a multi-threaded server which can receive multiple requests at the same time.
The server manages a session list.
When a request is received, the thread handling the request has to identify if a session is already open (in the session list) for the demanding client, or open a new one in case that client hasn't a session open yet.
So far so good. I protect the session list with a mutex so when a request comes in, the list is locked, browsed till the according connection is found and then unlocked and a pointer to the session returned (in that order).

**Now my question:**
Considering that a multiple requests can be received for the same client (and all of them have to get treated), what would be the best practice to protect the sessions themselves (knowing operations possible on the sessions are modify session info but that the session can also get deleted by request)?

**Example:**
Two incoming requests. First request locks list, finds session, unlocks list and gets session.
The second request does the same after the list has been unlocked.
Now both have a handle to the same session.

***Problem:***
What if one of the request is meant to close the session? The other request would now have a handle to that session but would not be aware it has been closed (and deleted).

What solution would you propose?

Thak you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a typical use case of the observer pattern.

Observer are requests/clients.
Subject is the session. When an event modify the session, all request/clients based on this session are notifyied something occured on the session.

So, the session object has a list of request/client. When something modifies the state of the session, all elements of this list are notifyied, synchronously. When notifying, you can embedded more or less information depending of your needs.

The typical trap of this approach is the notification cycle. session notifies a request which modify the session, etc.